# Access data of Worker service .NET core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, .net-core-service-worker

I developed an heavy engine, the heart of my app.
It consist in a infinite loop of:

- Acquiring frames from n cameras (h264 decoding)
- Do neural network elaboration on those frames
- Identify object, faces ecc.

The service will use a lot of GPU and RAM

I'm trying to interface this engine with a number of clients that will have access to, let's say generic real-time informations in the form of jsons.
I'm thinking to interface those clients through web apis (because of their scalability to e.g. apps, and generic platforms, i will need them later).

I thought the best way to achieve this was with a .NET core 3 worker service and, on top of it, an asp net api interface.

I'm asking what would be the best solution to achieve this: is the new worker service a best fit for my requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it using the *IHostedService* interface.
If you are in need for real-time communications, consider using *SignalR*.

Comment: And would be ok doing heavy image processing in an IHostedService? I've always seen light operations or simple dB access in those services

Comment: I think this is what it's meant for, you can refer to the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).
Also you can use _BackgroundService_ which is a base class implementing the _IHostedService_ interface.

Comment: Ok, let's say i put my 'core' inside an IHostedService, then how would i host the apis to communicate with my clients ?

Comment: Using ASP.NET Core, you can host the service and the APIs under the same umbrella. See example [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/hosted-services/samples/3.x/BackgroundTasksSample)

Comment: Ok, what i was missing was the dependency injection.
To let communicate my worker with my API i can use an injection to get the data i need without static fields.
More here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1